# Story Identification : "wish-gone-wrong" children's film

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a children's film (possibly TV show episode), that was likely either British or Australian.

I don't remember much about the film except that the protagonist was a male child/tween who wanted to be closer to a girl. One of his wishes resulted in him becoming her baby.

There was some kind of entity following him and responsible for granting his wishes.

Film/show was likely made in the early 90s and was live action.

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: @E.Z.Hart live action

Comment: How were the wishes granted? By a furry creature living on a beach?

Comment: @Covertwalrus I think a fairy or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

I'm extremely confident that what you are referring to is "The Big Wish", which as you mentioned was an Australian production, that was part of a TV series of Australian stories.

As well as being turned into the baby "to be someone that she will find adorable", his other wishes result in hime being turned into a girl, bully etc.

He was followed around by a being like you mentioned, granting his wishes. There is a trailer for the show [here on Youtube, The Big Wish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyEugYcBy5A)

Comment: A clip of the "being turned into a baby" is [here](http://aso.gov.au/titles/tv/big-wish/clip3/)

Comment: Also, the Australian Screen Archive listing is [http://aso.gov.au/titles/tv/big-wish/](here at http://aso.gov.au/titles/tv/big-wish/)